# What does it mean 'the exam is under referral'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence:

> The exam is **under referral**, because there was no accompaniment.

It's about music exam and it's the reply on the question how the exam went.

Does it mean the exam went bad (e.g. student fault), or everything is fine (good) or the exam is postponed?

Comment: Could you give more details? Who is the author of the message, and who is its reciipent? What kind of exam was taken? I don't understand this sentence at all.

Comment: @CopperKettle It's about music exam and it was texted by the student's parent after asked how was the exam of her daughter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the student's parent is leaving out a couple of details - perhaps because the situation is stressful and the decision is in doubt.

While technically it means that the exam itself is being referred to someone or something for a particular process, I would imagine that what it really means in the context is that the *result* of the examination is being referred to another party.

Both meanings would imply that whoever or whatever is being referred to has the authority to approve or reject the examination, or result, respectively.

Comment: It could make sense, but it also saying 'because there was no accompaniment'? So it sounds like there is some hidden negative meaning like excuse or something was missing.

Comment: @kenorb It appears to me that the examiners expected the student's performance to be "accompanied" - that she would sing or play along with an accompanist, perhaps a pianist. Because there was no accompaniment there may have been some question about whether the performance satisfied the technical requirements and it is that which is under review. One of a musician's critical skills is the ability to coordinate with other performers.